# Confusion regarding direct substition method of finding limits and using it to prove continuity of a function.

Tags: limits, continuity

To evaluate a limit, we often use direct substitution, assuming the function is continuous and hence the limit is equal to the functional value. But in textbooks, often direct substitution is used to prove that a function is continuous at a point. Isn't this proof circular, because we assume a function to be continuous and hence prove it is continuous? Is there a more valid way to prove a function is continuous without using direct substitution, i.e., to show that limiting value is equal to value of function at some value of x? (For single variable functions)

Comment: Can you provide an example of such circular proof?

Comment: For example, consider the proof that sin x is continuous onall reals: consider any real no. c. At c, value of function is sin c, and by direct substitution, limit of sin x as x tends to c is also sin c. Since functional value = limit, function is continuous. Isn't this a cyclc proof, because the limit was evaluated using the fact that the function was continuous in the first place. How else would you prove that sin x is continuous on all reals?

Comment: @AvyakthaAchar I agree with you that the proof in your comment above is circular. When I've seen proofs of continuity of $\sin x$ they were based on using the difference formula for sine, and some facts about sine and cosine.

Comment: I think that involves epsilon delta definion of limits. Is there a way to prove that sin x is continuous without using epsilon delta definion?

Comment: Irrc that does not require epsilon-delta proof, but rather shows that $\sin x$ is Lipshitz. Proof that Lipshitz functions are continous can be done using Haine's definition of continuity, so no epsilon-delta at all.

Comment: Thank you! @Esgeriath

Comment: That $\sin x, \cos x$ are continuous everywhere follows from the fact that they are continuous at $0$, using the angle difference formulas. That they are continuous at $0$ involves what is essentially an epsilon-delta argument, no matter what definition of continuity or theorems you use. When you look at the proofs of those theorems, they eventually go back to epsilon-delta (they may not use that language, talking about balls/intervals instead, but the radii of those balls/half-length of those intervals are the epsilon and delta).

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Thanks for the clarity!